# How to strip control characters when saving output to variable?

Tags: tcl, expect

Trying to strip control characters such as `^[[1m` and `^[(B^[[m` from `^[[1mfoo^[(B^[[m`.

```
$ cat test.sh
#! /bin/bash

bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

printf "%s\n" "Secret:"
printf "$bold%s$normal\n" "foo"
printf "%s\n" "Done"
```

```
$ cat test.exp
#!/usr/bin/expect

log_file -noappend ~/Desktop/test.log

spawn ~/Desktop/test.sh
expect {
  -re {Secret:\r\n(.+?)\r\nDone} {
    set secret $expect_out(1,string)
  }
}
```

```
$ expect ~/Desktop/test.exp
spawn ~/Desktop/test.sh
Secret:
foo
Done
```

```
$ cat -e ~/Desktop/test.log
spawn ~/Desktop/test.sh^M$
Secret:^M$
^[[1mfoo^[(B^[[m^M$
Done^M$
```

Comment: From all output, or just the logfile?

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequences depend on the TERM variable. You can avoid getting them in the first place by pretending to have a dumb terminal:

```
set env(TERM) dumb
spawn ~/Desktop/test.sh
```

This works for the provided example. If it will work in the real case is impossible to tell from the provided information. That depends on whether the program actually uses termcaps to generate the escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way in `expect` to add hooks to manipulate the data being read before it's matched/logged/etc. However, you can add another layer into your pipeline to strip ANSI escapes from what the real program being run outputs before `expect` sees it by adjusting your `test.exp`:

```
set csi_re [subst -nocommands {\x1B\\[[\x30-\x3F]*[\x20-\x2F]*[\x40-\x7E]}]
spawn sh -c "~/Desktop/test.sh | sed 's/$csi_re//g'"
```

This uses `sed` to strip out all strings that match [ANSI terminal CSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_(Control_Sequence_Introducer)_sequences) from `test.sh`'s output.

Comment: You could also put that through `regsub` on the Tcl side of things.

Comment: That won't affect the log, which seemed important to OP.